# SyndicationFeed only returns the first item

Tags: c#, rss, rss-reader, syndication-feed

I'm trying to get SyndicationFeed to work, but my code seems to only return back the first item (in this case, the first title tag)... I've looked at several tutorials to see if I was doing it wrong and even copied exactly what the code was from those tutorials, but they are resulted in the same thing - the first item being shown.

Here is the code:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("http://www.goal.com/en-us/feeds/news?fmt=rss&ICID=OP");
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

foreach(SyndicationItem item in feed.Items) {
    Console.WriteLine(feed.Title.Text);
}
Console.WriteLine("Enter to quit");
Console.ReadLine();
```

This returns something like:

```
Goal.com News - English - America
Goal.com News - English - America
Goal.com News - English - America
Goal.com News - English - America
...
Enter to quit
```

I've also tried multiple rss feed but get the same results. Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

It's a trivial error. You're outputting the title of the feed instead of the individual items:

```
foreach(SyndicationItem item in feed.Items) {
    Console.WriteLine(feed.Title.Text);
}
```

Instead, try

```
foreach(SyndicationItem item in feed.Items) {
    Console.WriteLine(item.Title.Text);
}
```